# Is there a way to use np.save (or np.savetxt) in a loop? I have a very large dataset and so cannot collect the parts into one big array

Tags: python, loops, append, save

I'm not sure why the following basic example of what I'm trying to achieve doesn't work:

```
    number = 10    #the number of iterations
    thing = np.array([1,2,3])

    f = open('a.npy', 'ab')   #open a file for appending
    for i in range(number):
        np.save(f, thing) #save the thing to a file
    
    with open('a.npy', 'rb') as f:  #open a file for reading
        a = np.load(f)
    print(a) #this just returns [1,2,3] (not this ten times which is what I want).
```

'''

Comment: can you add the expected output for `print(a)`?

Comment: Yes so I want it to the the an array consisting of the array I’m saving, the ‘number’ of times

Comment: I.e. [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],...,[1,2,3]]